# Why is this question about math notation closed as off topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Can anyone explain to me, [why my question got closed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74169/how-to-say-such-thing-in-english-216) as off topic ?

I was asking about how to pronounce this symbol, as I find it hard to Google for a "symbol"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that it's hard to impossible to google for symbols. You can, however, search Wikipedia for them. If you type a single symbol into Wikipedia's search box, it will take you to the corresponding article. Also, in your question you say "I know '^' means 'power'". So alternatively, you could have looked up that word rather than the symbol.

In the very first sentence on our [About](https://english.stackexchange.com/about) page, you will find this site described as a "community driven Q&A for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts". In other words, not all questions about English are on-topic here; certain things are just too basic, and we expect people to have a certain grasp of the language in order to participate.

We are aware of the drawbacks; just because a question is too basic *for this particular site*, doesn't mean it's not genuine or useful. Which is why there is now a proposed sister site targeted specifically at [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners).

Comment: I use [this site](http://www.symbolhound.com/) to search for symbols. Namely for programming, but it could be useful.

Comment: I just voted to close the "main" question as General Reference. For most purposes, the symbol is called a **caret**, for which the pronunciation is definitely GR. True, asked to "read aloud" the specific text strings **a ^ 2** or **a ^ 3** many people would say **a squared** or **a cubed**, but for **a ^ b** surely everyone would say **a [raised] to the power of b**. The "full text" form of mathematical symbols must be either Off Topic or General Reference, imho.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why it was closed.

- it is not off-topic
- it is not too local: obviously the OP doesn't want just those particular numbers pronounced
- it might still be too basic or general reference except

  - the given answers still don't cover how native English speakers (of mathematics) actually do it in general
  - the link that Matt gave gives a formal way of saying it but not what people actual use in practice
  - that method of looking up symbols is not commonly known
- also, I have an answer which I think will answer things well for you (which is why I'm responding here)

However, closing is a multi-person thing; there's no dictator (oh, except for mods who can just do it themselves) and everybody has their own reasons (or possibly on the bandwagon).

I have voted to reopen, but again, that's also a multiperson thing (except for mods who can just do it themselves).

Answer (score -1):

I think I voted to close as too localised. This is because you're asking how to pronounce 2^16. There are an infinite number of powers 2 can be raised to, and an infinite number of number that can be raised to a power. Asking for that specific one is too localised.

If you meant it as an example, then making that clear would improve the question.

Given that you already know that `^` means *power*, did you look in a dictionary, or wikipedia about mathematical power?

In case you are unaware, you can lookup symbols in Wikipedia like this: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/^](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%5E) and that will allow you to find out what you need to know.

I don't know for certain why the question is closed as off topic. RegDwight is better placed to answer that.

Comment: To localized? I'm pretty sure that was just an example.

Comment: @Luke did you read the question before the edit? It's quite specific.

Comment: I should have checked. I see what you mean.